# Почему Google Chrome под Mac открывает window.open как вкладку?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

При вызове функции

```
window.open('href', '_blank', 'width=400,height=250');
```

во всех (популярных) браузерах и на всех (популярных) платформах открывается окно указанных размеров (400x250)
Но в Google Chrome под Mac открывается новая вкладка.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?
Это баг или есть какие нибудь дополнительные настройки?

Comment: Ну и правильно делает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось проблема заключалась в использовании на Mac полноэкранного режима браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Это в настройках браузера пользователь может выбрать - новое окно или таб, со своей стороны вы не можете повлиять.

Comment: О где это настраивается? У меня везде и всюду окно - видимо по умолчанию. И только на одном браузере вкладка - там наверное и сменил настройку.